# Intergral of Brownian motion w.r.t. Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic

[image]

I don't understand why  $S$ (highlight on picture), I learned
$$\int_0^t W(s) dW(s) = \left. \frac{1}{2} (W^2(s)-s) \right \vert_0^t $$

everyone please explain for me. Thank you

Comment: The surprise is not whether there's an extra "s" term, it is how you were able to approximate a very complex integral in the first place (dW is not small enough for normal approximations to work - riemann integrals rely on slicing the "dW" term in as small pieces as one needs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply Ito's lemma to $f(W_t) = W_t^2$ then
$$
f(W_T) = f(W_0) + \int_0^T f'(W_t) dW_t + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^T f''(W_t) dt. 
$$
Thus
$$
W_T^2 =  2 \int_0^T W_tdW_t + \frac12 2 T =  2 \int_0^T W_tdW_t + T.
$$
If we rearrange terms then we get
$$
\int_0^T W_tdW_t = (W_T^2-T)/2.
$$

Answer (score 6):

While Richard's answer is technically correct, just saying the result can be obtained using Ito's formula doesn't make the issue much clearer. So let me go into the *microscopics* of the issue.

The Ito integral is defined in the following way. Suppose we divide the time interval $[0,t]$ into $n$ pieces with $t_i = i~dt$ where $dt=\frac{t}{n}$ then we define the Ito integral as
$$
\int_0^t G(t') dW(t') = {\text{ms-lim}}_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n G(t_{i-1}) ( W_{t_i} - W_{t_{i-1}})~,
$$
where the mean-square limit is defined in the following way:
$$
{\text{ms-lim}}_{n\to \infty} X_n = X \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} \langle (X_n - X)^2 \rangle =0~.
$$

Now let us evaluate the expression we would get on the RHS when evaluating $\int_0^t W(s) dW(s)$ from the above definition:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
Y^{(1)}_n &=& \sum_{i=1}^n W_{t_{i-1}} (W_{t_i} - W_{t_{i-1}})~.
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Now noting each increment $(W_{t_i} - W_{t_{i-1}}) = \sqrt{dt} \mathcal N_{i-1}(0,1)$ is an **independent normal** distribution we get
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
Y^{(1)}_n &=& dt \sum_{i > j} \mathcal N_i(0,1) \mathcal N_j(0,1)~.
\end{eqnarray}
$$
The other expression we get from the discretized version of the RHS of the standard answer $\int_0^t W(s) dW(s)=\frac{1}{2} (W(t)^2 - t)$ is
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
Y^{(2)}_n &=& \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{dt} \sum_{i =1}^n \mathcal N_i(0,1)\right)^2 -  \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n dt~.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Now if we can just show that the two expressions are same in the mean-square limit we are done. We see that
$$\begin{eqnarray}
&& \lim_{n \to \infty} \langle (Y^{(2)}_n - Y^{(1)}_n)^2 \rangle \\
&=& \lim_{n \to \infty} \langle \left( \frac{dt}{2} \left[ \left( \sum_{i,j} - \sum_{i>j} - \sum_{j>i} \right) \biggl( \mathcal N_i(0,1) \mathcal N_j(0,1) \biggr) - \sum_{i} 1 \right] \right)^2 \rangle \\
&=& \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{dt^2}{4}  \langle \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \mathcal N_i(0,1)^2 -n\right)^2 \rangle \\
&=& \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{dt^2}{4} \langle (\chi_n^2 -n)^2 \rangle \\
&=& \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{dt^2}{4} \operatorname{Var}(\chi_n^2)\\
&=& \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{dt^2}{2} n \\
&=& \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{t^2}{2n} \\
&=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Here we used the results that the squares of $n$ standard normals is a chi-square with degree $n$ and that the same has mean $n$ and variance $2n$.

Hence we are able to prove in detail why $\int_0^t W(s) dW(s)=\frac{1}{2} (W(t)^2 - t)$.

Comment: Thanks for providing the details. Yes in fact this shed some more light on the issue ... with $W_t^2$ the random term shows up squared and with $t$ the variance shows up and this is all that remains if I intergrate BM w.r.t BM (in the mean squared sense) ...

Answer (score 1):

The surprise is not whether there's an extra "s" term, it is how you were able to approximate a very complex sum in the first place (dW is not small enough for normal approximations to work - riemann integrals rely on slicing the "dW" term in as small pieces as one needs). So Ito discovered you could still approximate (simplify) the integrals because you can make dW^2 as small as possible. That is Ito's lemma.

It is a neat coincidence that you can look at it as a quadratic adjustment to the normal case.

Comment: Can I help you with anything specific? @JanStuller